# Is it possible to publish plug-in app to iOS AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store, publish

Of course only Apple knows, I just wonder may I publish my plug-in app to iOS AppStore. My app cannot be launched as standalone, but should be launched by other specific app. (In fact, it needs other app's information via URL Scheme).

Will it be approved by Apple AppStore Review Team? Or should I implement any additional feature for standalone? Thank you for your any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Store Review Guidelines

**2. Functionality**

2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: I read it already but may be I misunderstood that clause. I didn't know that it's applied to my case. I think I must do something... thanks!